# Why is my code not working? (Beginner programmer, python 1st language)

Tags: python

I need some major improvements in my programming/coding and it's already been a month of this computer language field.

Right now I'm trying to create a class with 3 functions (lunch, breakfast, and dinner) and let's say I want to call the function lunch and add 'Strawberry' to the lunch list; it's supposed to add 1 to the list count (`list_count`) for amount of foods entered in the list count so far, and adds 'strawberry' to the dictionary.

So what I'm trying to do is I created a blank dictionary list (`lunch_list`) and created a starting count of food items (`lunch_count`)

So if I call lunch in the Food class, I'm trying to make the result like this:

```
list_count: 1
lunch_name: Strawberry
lunch_list = {1:'Strawberry'}
```

I was ready to write this script but after writing this I confused myself a lot more. I feel lost. This is going to be embarassing for me but here is my code:

```
class Food():

    lunch_count = 0
    lunch_list = {}

    def __init__(self, food_name):
        self.food_name = food_name 

    def lunch(self, lunch_count):
        lunch_count += 1
        lunch_list[lunch_count] = self.food_name
        return lunch_list




strawberry = Food('Strawberry')

print strawberry.lunch('Strawberry')
```

Comment: `global` equal to `self` in a class. Don't write any one class without `docstring`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like your 'Strawberry' parameter matches the lunch_count parameter in your lunch function. In the lunch method, you then can increment it by one every time you call lunch, rather than adding it as a parameter.

If you are new to Python, I would recommend [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/).

```
class Food():
    lunch_count = 0
    lunch_list = {}

    def __init__(self, food_name):
        self.food_name = food_name

    def lunch(self):
        Food.lunch_count += 1
        Food.lunch_list[Food.lunch_count] = self.food_name
        return Food.lunch_list

strawberry = Food('Strawberry')

print strawberry.lunch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Food():

    lunch_count = 0
    lunch_list = {}

    def __init__(self, food_name):
        self.lc = None
        self.food_name = food_name 

    def lunch(self):
        Food.lunch_count += 1
        self.lc = Food.lunch_count
        Food.lunch_list[Food.lunch_count] = self.food_name
        return Food.lunch_list




strawberry = Food('Strawberry')

result = strawberry.lunch()
print strawberry.lc
print strawberry.food_name
print result
```

Comment: @Rawing works as a charm. I hope now you are happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read and understand.

```
lunch_count=0
lunch_item=""
lunch_menu={}
while lunch_item != "quit":
    lunch_item=input("Enter Item: ")
    menu_item=str(lunch_item)
    lunch_count+=1
    lunch_menu.update({lunch_count:menu_item})
    print(lunch_menu)
else:
    print("exiting")
```

Wrap this in a function and it adds an item and the count gets updated along with the newly entered string

Using python 3.5.2

If you like my answer please click the green arrow. 
Thanks.